# Strange Call in access.log

Tags: server, web-config

I found some strange call in my website access.log

This call come from where ? And How can i block it ?

```
> 40.77.167.156 - - [06/Jan/2019:14:18:16 +0100] "GET /nouvelles/news-k-1/17451-fight-card-glory-world-series-avec-semmy-schilt-vs-brice-guidon
> HTTP/1.1" 404 4060 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0;
> +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
```

Comment: Whats strange about it? Bingbot is Bing/Microsoft crawler to index your site. Google and Yahoo have similar things. This makes your site visible in the Bing search engine. You can requst a crawler not index your site via `robots.txt` file, in the root directory of your site.

Comment: so isn't a problem when we found something like that.

Comment: Not unless it's causing issues. This is most likely fine if you want a public website.